# Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'

Tags: typescript

I want to change `{nama: 'saya', siapa: 'dia'},` to `{nama: 'saya'}, {siapa: 'dia'}, ...`

This is my script:

```
var array : string[][] = [];
var input = {nama: 'saya', siapa: 'dia'}
for(var inputs in input){
    array.push({[inputs]: input[inputs]});
}
```

But I'm getting a warning like this:

> Argument of type '{ [x: string]: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[]'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the message is telling you that you are passing an object where an array is expected.

You probably meant

```
 var array : {[x: string]: any}[] = [];
```

Since you are trying to create an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Here's a simpler way:

```
// TypeScript infers the type as {[x: string]: any;}[]
const arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({[key]: obj[key]}));
```

Comment: ```var array : string[][] = [];
var input = {nama: 'saya', siapa: 'dia'}
for(var inputs in input){                                                                
 array.push({[inputs]: input[inputs]}); /// i'm get warning from this
} ```

Comment: It seems to work for here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20array%20%3A%20%7B%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%7D%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Avar%20input%20%3D%20%7Bnama%3A%20'saya'%2C%20siapa%3A%20'dia'%7D%0D%0Afor(var%20inputs%20in%20input)%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20array.push(%7B%5Binputs%5D%3A%20input%5Binputs%5D%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%20

Comment: Yes ia work, but why the response : `12` and not `{nama: 'saya'}, {siapa: 'dia'}, ...`